# SCM-Manager with Xcode

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

I have installed [SCM-Manager](http://www.scm-manager.org/). I would like to use it in the future for version control. The problem is, I cannot add it as a repository in Xcode, and I cannot clone it from command line:

```
$ git clone http://127.0.0.1:8080/scm/git/MyRepo
Cloning into 'MyRepo'...
Checking connectivity... done.
warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.
$
```

In Xcode I get this message:

```
fatal: unable to access 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/scm/git/MyRepo/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

SCM server logs this

```
failed to read basic auth credentials
```

I have tried to install on different server, checkout with different user, nothing helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first message means that you have cloned an empty repository. The message is only a warning and the repository is fully functional. A better way is to create the "bare" repository in SCM-Manager and add the remote reference to a local created repository:

```
git init MyRepo
git-remote add origin http://127.0.0.1:8080/scm/git/MyRepo/
```

The messages from Xcode sounds like missing credentials.